# 404 on question listed in "Related" column

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

Look at the related section on this question: [What makes the Blackberry device and network more secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/9929/396)

and it links to the following missing article: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/how-to-be-good-it-network-hacker

It was probably a low quality post and deleted... but it still shows up in the list.  I'm not sure if this is indicative of a bigger issue but want to make you aware.

Comment: Actually the question does exist, but it is deleted as you said - that's why you get 404, only moderators can see it. Regardless, I too would see this as a bug - deleted questions should not appear in the related questions.

Comment: @AviD I think you mean deleted, not closed. Closed questions are visible to everyone, even those without an account can see closed questions. Deleted questions are only visible to 10K users and diamond mods. Closed questions are displayed in the related links sidebar. However, my understanding is that deleted questions should not show up.

Comment: @ZulyGonzalez of course you're correct. Replace "closed" with "deleted". Nevermind, I will...

Comment: @AviD I think you're right about it being a bug though. Deleted questions shouldn't show up in the related links sidebar. You can delete my comment, or at least edit out the part about closed vs deleted. I just wanted to clarify for everyone.

Comment: I would suggest posting (or migrating) this to [meta.se], or checking for a duplicate question there.  I'm sure this isn't just something that affects our site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Related questions box show deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/related-questions-box-show-deleted-questions)

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). [Answered by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/related-questions-box-show-deleted-questions/71506#71506):

> It *is* possible for related questions to show a deleted question, as those lists are only rebuilt..
>
> - any time the question or any of its answers are edited
> - any time a new answer is provided
> - randomly 30% chance of rebuilding triggered by page view, once the question is older than 30 days

Comment: I hate it when they call this sort of thing [tag:status-bydesign].  It's like they're saying they *want* the website to behave in a way contrary to what would benefit the users.